# PC Cursor (sometimes) stuck at SizeAll caused by Logitech G9

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, logitech

We've noticed some strange Cursor behavior, which we suspect is a result of one of our Cursor canging methods. Just sometimes, our pc keeps showing the SizeAll cursor. Everywhere, in every application. Now, we never use the SizeAll cursor anywhere in our code, but we can "Unstuck" the cursor when following code is executed.

We suspect the problem to be something with the static Cursor Property, but cannot identify the error.

What's wrong with the code?

Thanks everyone though.

```
static class GlobalVars
{

    private static Cursor handOpenCursor;

    public static Cursor HandOpenCursor
    {

        get 
        {
            if (handOpenCursor == null)
            {
                string cursorPath = System.IO.Path.Combine( ApplicatiePaths.ImagePath, @"hand_open.cur" );
                handOpenCursor = new Cursor(cursorPath);
                return handOpenCursor;
            }
            else
            {
                return handOpenCursor;
            }
        }
        set 
        {
            handOpenCursor = value;
        }
    }
}


.....



private static void panel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((Control)sender).Cursor = GlobalVars.HandOpenCursor;
}
```

Comment: First, nice name. I hope it was meant as a musical reference. Second, please don't duplicate tags like "C# / .NET" in the title. Just leave those in the tags.

Comment: There's no code in your snippet that restores the cursor.  Where is it?

Comment: @John: First, thanks. :-) Always have to smile when doing or reading Start -> Run -> CMD :-). Second, ok, sorry, won't do it again.

@Hans: The same "MouseDown" event shows the "Hand drag" cursor , while MouseUp resets to the default cursor. It uses the same logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after 3 months I finally identiefied the problem. it wasn't .NET or XP, but I have a Logitech G9 Mouse with custom software.

When the cursor is stuck, and I go to Control Panel -> Mouse -> Pointer schemes, the right scheme is selcted (windows default), but ALL CURSORS of the scheme are the same SizeAll cursor?!?!

I suspect the G9 driver causes this crazy behavior.
Selecting another scheme and then again "Windows Default" solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what wrong with this static class, except that it is thread unsafe. Other thing that if you set custom cursor for some action you then need to reset cursor to normal state.
For example in this case:

```
  this.Cursor = Cursor.Wait;
  throw new Exception();
  this.Cursor = Cursor.Default;
```

Cursor will not be reset.

Comment: Two threads can execute new Cursor(cursorPath) at the same time, that will cause an Exception.

Comment: Nah, he'd get an InvalidOperationException